# Unlisted ethereum wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Unlisted ethereum wallet. Maybe can you help me?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well. I was in ropsten.

I noticed when I started the geth client directly and then tried to access the Mist wallet, was getting this error. But when I just started the Mist wallet directly without starting a geth client then was able to access the wallet UI.

I then tried initializing the geth with a new genesis config file. After doing that started the geth with a new networkid and on trying to access the Mist i was able to open it. So didn't face the error anymore

When I started with a different networkid starting with number different from 1 could again access my wallet.